# Eclipse Paho MQTT : disable offline buffering of messages in Python client

Tags: python, eclipse, mqtt, paho

As stated on [this page](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/), the Eclipse Paho Python client provides a buffer for messages not sent when the client is offline, these messages are finally sent when the client reconnects to the broker.

Is there a way to disable this feature to prevent server flooding when a large number of clients reconnects at the same time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the `reinitialise()` method will clear stored messages.

From the doc [here](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/python/docs/#constructor-reinitialise)

> clean_session
>
> ```
> a boolean that determines the client type. If True, the broker will remove all information about this client when it disconnects. If
> ```
>
> False, the client is a durable client and subscription information and
>   queued messages will be retained when the client disconnects.
>
> Note that a client will never discard its own outgoing messages on disconnect. Calling connect() or reconnect() will cause the messages
>   to be resent. Use reinitialise() to reset a client to its original
>   state.

Documentation for reinitialise is here:

> reinitialise()
>
> `reinitialise(client_id="", clean_session=True, userdata=None)`
>
> The reinitialise() function resets the client to its starting state as
>   if it had just been created. It takes the same arguments as the
>   Client() constructor. Example
>
> `mqttc.reinitialise()`

You can set this up to be called in the `on_disconnect` call back.

Comment: Thank you very much that was just the function I needed